# Forbidden address access in try block

Tags: c++, linux, crash, try-catch

I have a user space code as follows,

```
try
{
some code
...
code that tries accessing forbidden address
...
some code
}
catch (all exceptions)
{
some logs
}
```

Will the kernel send the `SIGSEGV` signal to the user process for this invalid access and what will be the `default` behaviour(dont have any signal handlers installed). Will the system `crash`.

Comment: There is no try/catch in C.  Consider using the c++ tag.

Comment: what method are you using to "access forbidden address"? (and why would you even be doing that)?
If you're e.g. simply dereferencing a NULL pointer, you will get a sigsegv under linux, but not an exception; you can install a signal handler, but that's platform specific

Comment: #nyarlathotep Its not on purpose. Mine is a large application where there are lot of chances of invalid memory accesses. like a traversal of a linked list.

Answer (score 1):

> code that tries accessing forbidden address

You cannot catch this with `C++ exceptions`. Only `platform-dependent` solutions.

Comment: Thanks. What is platform-dependent?

Comment: @Sibi non cross-platform solutions. SEH for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

An exception is not generated in this case. You need to set the signal handler. Take a look into [man signal](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?signal%207) how to do it.

For [example](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/code-examples/sigaction) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

static void hdl (int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context)
{
    printf ("Sending PID: %ld, UID: %ld\n",
            (long)siginfo->si_pid, (long)siginfo->si_uid);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigaction act;

    memset (&act, '\0', sizeof(act));

    /* Use the sa_sigaction field because the handles has two additional parameters */
    act.sa_sigaction = &hdl;

    /* The SA_SIGINFO flag tells sigaction() to use the sa_sigaction field, not sa_handler. */
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    if (sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, NULL) < 0) {
        perror ("sigaction");
        return 1;
    }

    while (1)
        sleep (10);

    return 0;
}
```